# Make jquery Load new HTML tag

Tags: jquery, html

HTML

```
<button onClick="a()">add box</button>
<div id ='u'></div>
```

JS

```
function a(){
    document.getGetElementById('u').innerHTML="<input id='eid' type='text'></input>"
}
$("#eid").keyup(function(){...});
```

jQuery does not find `$(#eid")`. How do I tell it I just created the text box. So recognise it.

I just updated my question(I first edited on the mobile app but app wasn't friendly to my code on techno H3)

Comment: There's not really enough information in your question to be certain, but have you tried jQuery's .on?  $("body").on('keyup', '#eid', function() { alert('You did a keyup!'); });  http://jsfiddle.net/hemnsoa7/

Comment: Another suggestion based on the code i see above. try using non intrusive programming as in "try binding a click event by jquery rather than providing onClick()." Like Jonathan asked, provide more information on the code.

Answer (score 1):

> jQuery does not find $(#eid"). How do I tell it I just created the
>   text box. So recognise it.

You didn't create anything into the DOM. When you called the `a()` function you only returned some string. That's all. It happens that this string represents some DOM input element which is fine, but until you insert this element into the actual DOM tree jQuery has no way of knowing about its existence.

So instead of just returning some string from this `a()` function you might consider actually inserting this input tag into the DOM tree somewhere. For example append it to the `<body>` of your DOM:

```
function a() {
    $('body').append('<input id="eid" type="text" />');
}
```

Now you can consider subscribing to some `keyup`  events on this DOM element. And since this is a newly dynamically inserted element you might do this in a *lively* manner using the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#eid', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: He'll want to use $(document).on('keyup' ... ) instead of click, as per the original post.

Comment: @Jonathan, good point, that't exactly what he will want to use instead of a `click` handler. Answer updated.

Comment: $(document).on('keyup', '#eid', function() {
    ...
}); did the job.  Thanks.